# Call a class function in __init__ from another class?

Tags: python, function, class, tkinter

First important note, I'm using tkinter. Each 'child' class has some unique widgets and functions, but every child class inherits the widgets and functions from the parent class (stuff like the background colour is defined here, because it's the same on every screen). When the user clicks certain buttons, the current class' screen is destroyed, and the next class is called. With that said, if I have a parent class like this:

```
class parent:
    def __init__(self):
        def back():
            if (someCondition == True):
                #some algorithm to go back, by deleting the current screen and popping the previous screen off a stack.
            else:
                change()

        #Algorithm to create main window
        self.back = Button(command=back)
```

And a child class like this

```
class child(parent):
    def __init__(self):
        parent.__init__(self)
        def change()
            #algorithm to change the contents of the screen, because in this unique case, I don't want to destroy the screen and call another one, I just want the contents of this screen to change.

        #Some algorithm to put unique widgets and such on this screen
```

How could I call the `change()` function from within the `back()` function? I tried 'child.change', but this returned an error message stating there was no attribute of 'child' called 'change'.

Comment: Nested functions can't be accessed directly. Why did you nest it inside `__init__` if you need to call it directly?

Comment: You nested `back` as a function in `__init__`. That makes it a local name in that function *only*, and only exists while `__init__` is running. Move your functions *out* of `__init__` and make them proper methods, or functions at the top level of the module, to reuse them.

Comment: The definition of `change` is fixed when you pass `back` to `Button()`, so structuring your code this way won't work.

Comment: `change` is not a class function in either class definition

Comment: I did try removing it from __init__ but it caused a large number of other errors. Because the Button to call 'back' is defined within __init__ as well, this line returns the error 'name 'back' is not defined'. Similarly, the change() function is called a few times from within the __init__ of the child class, so I can't remove that one without causing a large number of errors.

Comment: Ok, I get it! You mean I can make change() a class function, and call it even from within __init__ as child.change(). Ok, this works, thank you all.

Comment: There's simply no reason to create a nested function. As you can see, it makes development harder.

Comment: @BryanOakley Surely you mean that for this particular function, right? Because I think it makes the code easier to read when used properly as it indicates the scope of the nested method as narrow as they come.

Comment: @nae: yes, I mostly mean in this specific example. Nested functions are useful to solve a limited subset of problems.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to make `back` a normal method. The parent can call methods of the child in the normal way.

```
class Parent(object):
    def back(self):
        print("in parent.back()")
        self.change()

class Child(Parent):
    def change(self):
        print("in child.change()")

# create instance of child
child = Child()

# call the back function:
child.back()
```

The above code yields the following output:

```
in parent.back()
in child.change()
```

If you prefer, you can make `Parent.change()` throw an error, to force the child to implement it:

```
class Parent(object):
    ...
    def change(self):
        raise Exception("Child must implement 'change'")

class MisfitChild(Parent):
    pass
```

With the above, the following will throw an error:

```
child = MisfitChild()
child.back()
```